# flutter showDialog It doesn't show the error on the screen. Is there an error in the code?

Tags: flutter, dart

https://gist.github.com/bymaster66/48a43f0f5948da6e4cb4ddd36fbce8cf#file-gistfile1-txt

Can you help me how to fix this error?

I just started learning flutter language

I searched for the solution on the internet but could not find it.

It doesn't show the error on the screen. Is there an error in the code???

Comment: Can you post the github gist file in dart extension please?

Comment: how can I do that

Comment: create another gist with dart file extension and share it here